# Summarize data using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

I am a beginner to VBA. On sheet one I have data formatted like this:

**SHEET 1**

[image]

What I want to do is use VBA to spit out the following graph which dynamically populates the region depending on how many it finds:

**SHEET 2**

[image]

This is my first bit of VBA so I am struggling a bit. This is my idea of how to approach this problem:

[image]

My idea was to scroll down the string in my data in sheet1 col A and determine if it's a date we have seen before or not:

```
Public Sub Test()

ActiveSheet.Range("Sheet1!A1:A5000").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange.Range("Sheet2!A1"), Unique:=True

End Sub
```

**Questions**

1. Is this flow diagram taking the right approach?
2. If so, how do I implement this kind of "Is this unique, if so do this, if not do this" kind of setup.

How can I start this code so I have something to build on?

This is what I have so far:
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/employ/af67485b8acddce419a2/raw/6dda3bb1841517731867baec56a0bf2ecf7733a7/gistfile1.txt

Comment: Use `IF` statements to achieve your "Is unique, if so do this" approach. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx

Comment: How did you make the flow chart?

Comment: Looks like your trying to do with VBA what is already built-in to Excel via its Pivot Tables facility.

Comment: @DMM Correct! But pivot tables are next to useless due to the terrible graphing capability

Comment: why US in Mar 15 populating 2 instead of 4? Do you need to sum the values or just count them? If you need to count occurance then why Jan 15 EU is populating 2?

Comment: @Dubison Ack good spot. On sheet2 Mar15 should say 4 not 2

Comment: my proposal will be same with @DMM since pivot table can do these very easily. If you want you can copy and paste pivot results to a new sheet as values so you will have the same result as macro. But if you want to do it with macro no matter what then let me know pls.

Comment: @Dubison I have it working as a pivot but the problem is the pivot is struggling. The pivot chart is very basic and I can't include values from summaries. If I copy pivot table data it then isn't live. Pivot tables can't even do custom sorting other than alphabetical. They are really close but just a big crap. I'm still after a VBA approach if possible

Comment: You can make use of simple formulae to refer to entries in a pivot table (e.g. =B3 where the pivot table contains cell B3) to get round the "live" problem. You can sort a pivot table in any order you like using drag and drop to change the order of columns and rows. You can use the data from a pivot table (or a referenced copy) to create charts conventionally rather than using in-built Pivot Charts. Your demonstrated level of VBA knowledge suggests that Pivot Tables will be by far the most productive route for your efforts.

Comment: @DMM I can't see a way of using conventional charts for pivot table data it will only let me use pivotcharts which are useless. Unless I duplicate data which causes a load of problems

Comment: I suggest sorting by Date first, then by Region - this will give you an easy way to determine (and sum or count) the duplicates in both with logic relatively simple to implement (working on the subsets). At the end you can reverse the sorting to original if you add a temporary column with InitialSortIDs

Comment: @Jimmy Create a pivot table. Select the data you want from it. Create chart in usual way elsewhere on the worksheet.

Comment: @DMM I want it to update live and don't want to have to duplicate data

Comment: This is what I have so far https://gist.githubusercontent.com/employ/af67485b8acddce419a2/raw/6dda3bb1841517731867baec56a0bf2ecf7733a7/gistfile1.txt

Comment: @Jimmy Your `CheckDate` routine is comparing the value in the ActiveCell  (an arbitrary cell selected by the Excel user and mouse) with what's already in row A of  Sheet2. You need to provide CheckDate() with the value being checked from Sheet1 - preferably as an argument. You also need to manage how many values have already been put into row A so that if the value from Sheet 1 isn't matched you'll know precisely where it should be added. As I said earlier, given your demonstrated level of knowledge ... Pivot Tables. Over and out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For different approach please see below:

Sheet 1 layout (Source):

[image]

Sheet 2 Layout (Target):

[image]

```
Sub SalesRegion()
Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws1LastRow, ws2LastRow, salesVal  As Long
Dim destFind, dateFind As Range
Dim destStr As String
Dim dateStr As Date
Dim targetCol, targetRow As Long


Set wb = ActiveWorkbook '<- Your workbook
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")  '<- Your source worksheet
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2") '<- Your destination worksheet

ws1LastRow = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To ws1LastRow
destStr = ws1.Range("C" & i).Value
dateStr = ws1.Range("A" & i).Value
salesVal = ws1.Range("B" & i).Value

With ws2.Rows("1:1") '<- row on destination sheet which contains countries
    Set destFind = .Find(What:=destStr, _
        LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False)
            If Not destFind Is Nothing Then
                targetCol = destFind.Column
                With ws2.Columns("A:A") '<- Column on destination sheet which contains months
                'You may need to adjust date format below depending on your regional settings
                Set dateFind = .Find(What:=Format(ws1.Range("A" & i).Value, "MMM-yy"), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False)
                        If Not dateFind Is Nothing Then
                            targetRow = dateFind.Row
                            ws2.Cells(targetRow, targetCol).Value = ws2.Cells(targetRow, targetCol).Value + salesVal
                        Else
                            ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = dateStr
                            targetRow = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                            ws2.Cells(targetRow, targetCol).Value = salesVal

                        End If
                End With
            Else

            ws2.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Value = destStr
            targetCol = ws2.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

            With ws2.Columns("A:A") '<- Column on destination sheet which contains months
                'You may need to adjust date format below depending on your regional settings
            Set dateFind = .Find(What:=Format(ws1.Range("A" & i).Value, "MMM-yy"), _
                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False)
                    If Not dateFind Is Nothing Then
                        targetRow = dateFind.Row
                        ws2.Cells(targetRow, targetCol).Value = ws2.Cells(targetRow, targetCol).Value + salesVal

                        Else
                            ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = dateStr
                            targetRow = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                            ws2.Cells(targetRow, targetCol).Value = salesVal

                    End If
            End With
            End If
End With
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I agree with the others that you should look for a solution using the built-in capabilities of the `Pivot Table`.

Since you've mentioned that it does not meet your expectations, I threw together some code that works to summarize the data as you've requested. Let me know if it does the trick, if you need any added help adjusting it for your needs, or if you have any other general questions.

```
Sub SummarizeInNewSheet()
    Dim wsOrigin As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim rngOrigin As Range
    Dim oDict As Object
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim rngLocations As Range
    Dim nLastRow As Long
    Dim nLastCol As Long
    Dim rngInterior As Range
    Dim rngAllDates As Range
    Dim rngAllLocations As Range
    Dim rngAllSales As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wsOrigin = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsDest = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set rngOrigin = wsOrigin.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    Intersect(rngOrigin, wsOrigin.Columns(1)).Copy wsDest.Range("A1")
    wsDest.Range(wsDest.Range("A1"), wsDest.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes

    Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set rngLocations = wsDest.Range("B1")
    For Each cel In Intersect(rngOrigin, wsOrigin.Columns(3))
        If cel.Row = 1 Then
        Else
            If oDict.exists(cel.Value) Then
                'Do nothing for now
            Else
                oDict.Add cel.Value, 0
                rngLocations.Value = cel.Value
                Set rngLocations = rngLocations.Offset(, 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next cel

    nLastRow = wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    nLastCol = wsDest.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set rngInterior = wsDest.Range(wsDest.Range("B2"), wsDest.Cells(nLastRow, nLastCol))

    Set rngAllDates = wsOrigin.Range(wsOrigin.Range("A2"), wsOrigin.Range("A2").End(xlDown))
    Set rngAllSales = wsOrigin.Range(wsOrigin.Range("B2"), wsOrigin.Range("B2").End(xlDown))
    Set rngAllLocations = wsOrigin.Range(wsOrigin.Range("C2"), wsOrigin.Range("C2").End(xlDown))

    For Each cel In rngInterior
        cel.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(rngAllSales, rngAllDates, wsDest.Cells(cel.Row, 1), rngAllLocations, wsDest.Cells(1, cel.Column))
    Next cel

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```